# Implementing VisibleBoundsUpdatedEventHandler

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, vb.net

I have an ArcObjects add-in button that adds attribute value info as a text graphic into a map document layout.  Now, instead of using the add-in button click event, I would like the code to run on VisibleBoundsUpdatedEventHandler or when the active view has been updated.

Can this be implemented through add-ins?

The link below uses this for a panning tool.  I'm not sure how and where to begin to implement this.

http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=145041